# Efficient way to compute outer product for every row of a matrix

Tags: r

I need help in finding an *efficient* way of computing the **outer product** for every **row** of a matrix.

So far I've tried

```
X <- matrix(1:100, ncol=4)
lapply(1:i, function(i) tcrossprod(X[i,]))
```

which gives me the creeps as it is rather slow and cumbersome when applied to a "real-life" (aka "big") matrix.

Whether the type of the result is an array or a list doesn't matter.

Any ideas? `plyr` and friends are way to slow as well.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your actual matrix?

Comment: For what purpose do you want all of those outer products? (I'm asking because if you are going to use them in further operations, there may be better ways to carry out your calculations. The list or array you're asking for is from one perspective a **very** inefficient and redundant way to store information that's all already there in your matrix `X`!)

Comment: Josh is right--there may be a much better way to get your final result.  Now, given that each row's crossproduct is independent of all other rows, you'll have to execute as many `tcrossprod` calls as there are rows.  I rather suspect that the overhead involved with your loop, whether it be `*apply` or `for (i in 1:nrows(matrix))`, is minimal compared with the time required to do the cross products.

Comment: @joran: more than (700000/d) x (3*d) where d >= 1, just to give a number. For smaller problems I can see a variety of solutions that maybe trade off memory vs. speed.

Comment: @Josh, @Carl: For the current application that I'm working on, yes, you're absolutely right, there is a better solution, since I need `Y %*% t(Y)` where `Y` is some part (or the whole) of `X`. However, I would be interested in a general solution as there might (or might not ;-)) be cases where one would need the individual results.

Comment: Ok, now that I'm not confused by different mult signs anymore, that doesn't seem that big to me. What sort of execution time do you consider too slow?

Comment: Sorry about the mult-signs, let's just say that I'm using matrices with up to 5 million elements. I agree with you that they're not _that_ big, but on the other hand this is all in the context of an iterative algorithm which is why its performance impact isn't negligible. Apart from that I just realized a small typo in my above comment where it should have read `t(Y) %*% Y` instead of the other way around (although that really isn't so important wrt to the OP ;-)). Anyways, thanks for taking the time to look into this matter!

Answer (score 1):

Does the code below give you the desired output?  If so, is it fast enough on your data?

```
library(data.table)

# Example matrix
m <- matrix(1:100, ncol=4)

# Convert to data.table
X <- as.data.table(m)

# Add row numbers
X[,row:=1:nrow(X)]

# Reshape to long format
X.long<-data.table(reshape(X, direction="long", varying=list(rev(rev(names(X))[-1])), v.names="value", idvar="row", timevar="col", times=1:(ncol(X)-1)),key="row")

# Join the long data.table to itself, perform the products, and then reshape back to wide format
reshape(X.long[X.long,list(col=i.col, col.old=col, prod=value*i.value)], direction="wide", idvar=c("row","col"), timevar="col.old")

##     row col prod.1 prod.2 prod.3 prod.4
##  1:   1   1      1     26     51     76
##  2:   1   2     26    676   1326   1976
##  3:   1   3     51   1326   2601   3876
##  4:   1   4     76   1976   3876   5776
##  5:   2   1      4     54    104    154
##  6:   2   2     54    729   1404   2079
##  7:   2   3    104   1404   2704   4004
##  8:   2   4    154   2079   4004   5929
##  ... etc
```

Comment: Thank you. The output seems ok but, unfortunately, due to all the reshaping and using lists it's too slow. Didn't know about data.table though, thanks!

Comment: Do you have some sample data that is of the size of your actual data, and an amount of time for generating the outer product that would be acceptable?  Also, depending on what you're doing after the outer product operation, you may not need to do the reshape back to wide.  The general strategy for working with `data.table` seems to be "do everything in long and then summarize and reshape to wide at the end".